# jquery validation plugin and submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a `form` that is using jQuery validation and is also making ajax calls to a database via `php` to display information after the first select, and then after submit.

This is as close as I can get it to working.  The only remaining problem is that the `form` will allow the user to submit it when there are validation errors that should be corrected.

I believe the `submitHandler` is the key to making it work, but any code I have tried where I comment `//tried various things here` has caused various different problems.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../../jquery_theme/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#commentForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //tried various things here
        }
    });
 });

</script>

</head>
<body>


<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm"  >
<fieldset>

 <p> <label for="select_part">Select Part to Adjust Count</label></p>  

          <div>  <select name="id_part" id="select_part" class="required" >
                <option value="">---</option>
                <option value="1">option1</option>
                <option value="2">option2</option>

            </select>

                <div id="returnedValue" class="ajaxReturn"></div>
            </div>
                <br />

 <p>
 <label for="cname">Name</label>
 <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
 </p>
 <input id="submitForm" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 <p><div id="returns"></div></p>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validateTestDB.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the javascript that feeds info back to the page:

```
$('#select_part').change(function(){
var select_part = $('#select_part').val();


$.post('../../php/getCounts.php', { select_part: select_part}, function(data){
$('#returnedValue').hide().html(data).fadeIn(1200);


      });
   });

 $('#submitForm').click(function(){


var select_part = $('#select_part').val();
var name = $('#cname').val();
$.post('validateResult.php', {select_part: select_part, name: name}, function (data3){
    $('#returns').html(data3);
     });

});
```

I've been reading and trying things for two days, and I'm just stuck.

Comment: What errors in the validation could exist? Selecting an option will make the form valid, and thussly submittable. in your `$('#submitForm')` click handler, i don't see you doing any `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting. If you do that, the form will no longer submit. You can check `if($('#commentForm').valid()){ //submit logic to handle form }else{  return false; //form will not submit }`

Comment: move your logic of click on `submitForm` into `submitHandler` function without the `click` assignment and don't forget to return `false` at the end, otherwise it will `submit` the form again.

Comment: Ohgodwhy - It's a bit cropped down for brevity, but the form would fail validation if the user doesn't select anything, or if they do not put more than two characters in the name field.

The functionality to stop the form from submitting is built in to the Validate Plugin.  When I comment out all of the code related to the submit button in my javascript file, it works - as in, it will not submit until the errors are corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a click handler, `$('#submitForm').click()`, that is interfering with the `submitHandler:` inside the validation code.  This is redundant and the `.click()` handler should be removed in favor of the `submitHandler:`.   The desired code should then be placed *inside* the `submitHandler`, something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var select_part = $('#select_part').val();
            var name = $('#cname').val();
            $.post('validateResult.php', {select_part: select_part, name: name}, function (data3){
                $('#returns').html(data3);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, that was it Sparky672. I was able to figure it out from Anil Kumar's comment.

Thanks!

Comment: @EotS: No problem, I didn't read the comments.  I saw no answer posted, so I jumped in.