# Error image won't turn into success image, after filling then clearing a required textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tooltip

The scenario:

1. Leave the "TxtName" empty and submit; then, a red image will be displayed next to the textbox. Intended.
2. Fill the textbox with data **without submit**, then the red image will turn into green. Intended.
3. Clear the data in the textbox **and don't submit**. Then the green image didn't turn into red. **The problem!**

Here's the jQuery validation code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#BtnSubmit").click(function() {
            $("Form").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%= TxtName.UniqueID %>: { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    <%= TxtName.UniqueID %>: { required: "Name is required" }
                },
                success: function(element){
                    $(element).addClass("checked");
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    var container = $('<div />');
                    container.addClass('MyTooltip');
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                    error.wrap(container);
                    $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Where:

- The "errorImage" css class is the class that displays the red image.
- The "checked" css class is the class that displays the green image.
- The "error placement" section just displays the image (red/green) beside the textbox, and this image, when hovered on, will display a tooltip of the error message.

Here's the CSS if you need to look at it:

```
div.MyTooltip { 
    position: relative !important;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0px;
} 

div.MyTooltip:hover { 
    z-index: 1005;
} 

div.MyTooltip label { 
    display: none !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 11px;
} 

div.MyTooltip:hover label.error:not(.checked) { 
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 24px;
    width: 170px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    color: white; 
    opacity: 0.50;
    text-align: center;
} 

label.error + div.errorImage
{
    background: url('Images/error.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
} 

label.checked + div.errorImage
{
    background: url('Images/valid.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
} 

input.error, select.error {
    /*border-width: 1px;*/
    border-color: tomato;
}
```

The ASP .NET HTML is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBranchName" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the relevant HTML too.  And can you also construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: The HTML you posted is not useful.  Where is the _rendered_ HTML output of the form?  (pull up the rendered page and view source)  Also, where is a jsFiddle demo of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see it now.  You are incorrectly binding the button `click` event to `.validate()`.  This causes all kinds of weird issues since everything is re-intialized every time the button is clicked.

`.validate()` gets initialized **only once** *within DOM ready*.  Its built-in `submitHandler` already takes care of capturing the submit button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $("#BtnSubmit").click(function() {  // <-- remove this line!
        $("Form").validate({
            rules: {
                <%= TxtName.UniqueID %>: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                <%= TxtName.UniqueID %>: { required: "Name is required" }
            },
            success: function(element){
                $(element).addClass("checked");
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var container = $('<div />');
                container.addClass('MyTooltip');
                error.insertAfter(element);
                error.wrap(container);
                $("<div class='errorImage'></div>").insertAfter(error);
            }
        });
    // }); // <-- remove this line!
});
```

See a generic (since you provided no HTML) demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/RKSSp/

---

See these for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12989534/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068130/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107043/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692534/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936025/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101079/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609871/594235

Comment: I applied your suggestions but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @MohamedEmad, Until you can provide a jsFiddle demo, this is the best answer I have.  We are not here to simply service you... you must also apply some effort into showing your problem.